# SQL Calculate percent above or below

Tags: sql-server, percentage

I have the following values as result of a query. Based on the Value the Cell has to be color coded.

```
Value   Goal
------------
9.33    12
```

o   Cell containing value will be color coded based on goals entered as compared to value
   Cell to be colored green if value is at or below goal
   Cell to be colored yellow if value is within 5% above goal
   Cell to be colored red if value is more than 5% above goal

Please guide how to calculate Value 5% within or above goal

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the percentage or how to return a different color name per row? Color coding is a client concern, so you shouldn't have to do anything more than calculate the percentage.

Comment: I think `[Value_5+] = Goal * 1.05, [Value_5-] = Goal * 0.95`

Comment: @Jens,@Penagiotis,@Mikhail                                                                   I want to return a color name and client will handle coloring it. 
Value Goal  Color
--------------------
9.33 13    GREEN
Question is how to do this?
`SELECT CASE WHEN @Value < @Goal THEN 'GREEN'
 WHEN @Value --(0 to 5% above @Goal) 
  > @Goal THEN 'YELLOW'
 WHEN @Value  --(5% above goal)(5% above goal) 
  > @Goal THEN 'RED'`

Comment: `Value Goal  Color
-----------------------
9.33   13    GREEN`  Sorry guys, formatting gets messed up. Basically, want to return a field with color

Answer (score 0):

Test values:

```
DECLARE @t_temp TABLE (Val  NUMERIC(16,2),
                       Goal NUMERIC(16,2))

INSERT INTO @t_temp (Val, Goal)
VALUES (9.33, 12),
(12,12),
(12.15, 12),
(12.66, 12),
(14, 12);
```

Query:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE 
         WHEN Val <= Goal          THEN 'GREEN'
         WHEN Val <= (Goal * 1.05) THEN 'YELLOW'
         ELSE                           'RED'
       END AS 'Color'
FROM @t_temp;
```

Result:

```
Val                                     Goal                                    Color
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------
9.33                                    12.00                                   GREEN
12.00                                   12.00                                   GREEN
12.15                                   12.00                                   YELLOW
12.66                                   12.00                                   RED
14.00                                   12.00                                   RED
```

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @SilverFish Please mark your solution so your questions shows up as answered.